# Is this possible to run gradient descent to train SVMs?

Tags: machine-learning, svm

The classical implementation of SVMs usually use SMO algorithm to train SVMs, which is a bit clumsy and lengthy. Occasionally I saw this line of code :

```py
for ii in range(outer_loops * M):
        i = int(np.random.rand() * M)
        margin = Y[i] * np.dot(K[i, :], alpha)
        grad = M * L * K[:, i] * alpha[i]
        if (margin < 1):
            grad -=  Y[i] * K[:, i]
        alpha -=  grad / np.sqrt(ii + 1)
        alpha_avg += alpha
```

to train the parameters.

It confused me for hours, I have no idea where the gradient pops out as well as the weird `if` block to "update" the gradient when the margin falls below 1. But the results turns out fairly good.

So I really want to know why this code is justified, why it's OK to use gradient descent rather than convex optimization techniques.